# Text extraction using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, text-extraction

I have an text extraction algorithm in scala, I want to use spark on top of it. I am not able to understand how to use it as I am new to both spark and scala
My algorithm is like this

```
object HelloWorld {
    val algoobejct = new ObjectExtract
    var textFile = ("Path to text file")
  for each sentence in textFile
  {
    val instances = algoobject.extract(sentence);
      save instances to texFile
    }
```

I can have here multiple text files and these text files are a lot.

can anyone tell me how it can be done using spark ?
My algorithm is in scala so I will be using scala only to do this task.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Show your spark code and the error you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
val algoobejct = new ObjectExtract
val rdd = sparkContext.textFile("Path to text file")
rdd.map(sentence=>algoobject.extract(sentence)).saveAsTextFile("outputDirectory")
```

just make sure `algoobejct` extends `Serializable` otherwise it won't work